# How do I convert my text data type field into date? (Error Code: 1411)

Tags: mysql, sql

I am attempting to convert a text data type field of days of the week (below) into a date data type field.

| Day |
| --- |
| Friday |
| Monday |
| Saturday |
| Sunday |
| Thursday |
| Tuesday |
| Wednesday |

When I run:

```
UPDATE toronto_transport
SET Day = str_to_date(Day, "%W");
```

I receive the following: 'Error Code: 1411. Incorrect datetime value: 'Saturday' for function str_to_date'

I believe I am following the correct conventions as per [MySQL 8.0 reference manual section 12.7](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month) . Please correct me if I am wrong, I am clearly missing something here.

Steps to resolve this error as mentioned above, as well as attempting `"%w"` and `"%x"`.

Comment: Which Saturday date do you mean? Your task lacks input data to compute a single date.

Comment: @Serg I don't understand your question, sorry. I mean Saturday as Weekday name format ("%W"), as opposed to Day of the week format ("%w").  There is only one spelling of Saturday in my field also.

Comment: Weekday cannot be a date. Date value must identrify strictly one datetime point. Whereas the weekday cannot do this.

Comment: @Akina thank you for the clarifying. So what can Weekday be classified as? Is it its own thing, weekday?

Comment: Weekday is an attribute of the date which is derived value of this date/datetime value (knowing the date we can determine the weekday). Like a city name which is an attribute of an address, but at the same time the city itself is not an address.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a case expression :

```
update toronto_transport tt
set `Day` = case when `Day`='Sunday'     then 0
                 when `Day`='Monday'     then 1
                 when `Day`='Tuesday'    then 2
                 when `Day`='Wednesday'  then 3
                 when `Day`='Thursday'   then 4
                 when `Day`='Friday'     then 5
                 when `Day`='Saturday'   then 6
             end ;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/Xs464MAJ

Comment: I executed your suggestion, then followed with ```UPDATE toronto_transport
SET Day = STR_TO_DATE(Day, "%w");```. However, I still got the following: Error Code: 1411. Incorrect datetime value: '6' for function str_to_date. Seems to really dislike Saturdays.

Comment: @kevin_malone why do you still execute your query ? If the query above didn't help please share the expected output of the given data examples

Comment: I still attempted my query, as when I execute ```DESCRIBE toronto_transport;```. It tells me my Day field type is still text, as opposed to date type, which is my end goal.

Comment: @kevin_malone the only allowed format of [DATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html#:~:text=The%20DATE%20type%20is%20used,both%20date%20and%20time%20parts.) data type in MySQL is  `YYYY-MM-DD`.  You have to store proper dates or use int in your case . https://dbfiddle.uk/8hs32dgj